# How can I "properly" merge two cylinders so I can bevel the connection between them?

Tags: modifiers, bevel, boolean-modifier

I wanted to connect two different diameter cylinders and then smooth the edge between the two.

But I just couldn't get it to work. There always are two spots where the bevel looks weird (like in the picture) even when I removed the two big faces and connected all edges it still made the bevel look weird at two points.

As you can probably tell I'm new to Blender and any help and tips are appreciated!

Thank you!
[image: Here you can see my problem more clearly!]

Comment: Is it a bevel? Have your recalculated the normals before the bevel?

Comment: i think sharing your blend file is a good idea before we ask a lot of questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe things already went wrong in the modeling process, because if you follow these steps, you will get your desired result:

1. You will need three different cylinders. Let's call them *Main*, *Add* and *Cutter*. Arrange them like this:

   [image]
2. Give *Main* **a *Boolean Modifier* (set to union)** to combine *Main* and *Add*. You can hide the original *Add* object afterwards.
3. Give *Main* **another *Boolean Modifier* (set to difference)** to cut out the middle hole with the *Cutter*. You can now hide the *Cutter*.

   [image]
4. Apply Modifiers (1) + (2) in this order; you should get the following geometry. Now you need to select the desired edge rings (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>) and set their *Mean Bevel Weight* to 1 in the N-Panel:

   [image]
5. Then add a Bevel Modifier and set the limit method to Weight.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I think I made the mistake that Main wasn't overlapping with Add.

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible you don't *need* to 'merge 2 cylinders'?..

Can you can just <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the second from the outer faces of the first, and bevel?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would have modeled this completely different right from the start. The easiest and quickest way would be the one by @RobinBetts but here is another one so that you get an idea what other tools exist in Blender so that the *Boolean* modifier is not necessary.

I don't know if your cylinders and the hole have specific dimensions or if you just modeled them with random sizes - but it's quite easy to get something like this with the correct dimensions without any need for a *Boolean* modifier.

Let's say you want to create this thing: the base should have a radius of 1 m and be 0.2 m high, then it should extend upwards 1 m with a radius of 0.6 m (0.4 m smaller than the base) and there should be a vertical hole with a radius of 0.3 m (0.3 m less than the radius before, 0,7 m less than the base).

[image: schematics]

Then I would do it like that:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to *Add* a *Cylinder*. In the tool options, set the *Radius* to 1 m (if it isn't already) and the *Depth* to 0.2 m to get the base.

   [image: add base cylinder]
2. Next select the top face and hit <kbd>I</kbd> to inset the face followed by <kbd>.4</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to make the inner radius 0.6 m.

   [image: inset for upper cylinder]
3. With the inner face still selected press <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to extrude 1 m along the normal to get the height of the upper cylinder.

   [image: extrude upper cylinder]
4. To create a circle with 0.3 m radius for the hole, inset the top face by 0.3 m with <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>.3</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.

   [image: inset top hole radius]
5. Now select the bottom face of the base. This has a larger radius, so you need to inset it 0.7 m to get same radius for the hole, <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>.7</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.

   [image: bottom hole radius]
6. Now select both inner faces for the hole. From the viewport menu select *Edge* > *Bridge Edge Loops*. This way the top and bottom faces are deleted and their edges are connected to build the inner walls of the hole.

   [image: bridge edge loops]

And that's it for the modeling. You already got an accepted answer where the *Weight* method for the *Bevel* modifier is explained so I'll leave that to you, since your problem was primarily not the beveling itself but the mesh of your object.

[image: finished object]